# Eliminate persistent state selected value drop down - jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone, jquery-mobile

I have a drop down/select in a hybrid iOS-Black Berry app. I'm populating the drop down depending on certain variables, so the values change dynamically. The problem I'm having is that if the person makes a selection in the drop down, hits back, and goes back to the screen with the drop down, even if the selections are different now, the previously selected value in the drop down is still selected, on top, even when it's not supposed to be available.

I tried this code before populating the drop down:

```
mySelect.selectedIndex = 0
mySelect.empty()
```

I was expecting this to deselected the value and clear the drop down, but it doesn't. It does clears the drop down, but the old selection still there, selected, on top.

There are plenty of articles out there on how to KEEP persistent state, couldn't find any on how not to. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

***EDIT:***

How I populate the drop down - code is inside a function and the options change depending a variable value:

```
    myOptions = {
        1: 'aaaa',
        2: 'bbbb',
        3: 'cccc',
        4: 'dddd'
      }

$.each(myOptions, function (val, text) {
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
});
```

This function is inside a custom.js and its being call from another jQuery file. This is for a mobile application using jQuery Mobile.

***Things I have tried:***

```
mySelect.siblings('span').empty();

$("#id").selectmenu("refresh");

$("select[id$=mySelect] > option").remove();

$("select[id$=mySelect]").val('');
```

I have tried these inside the same function to fill the drop down, in another function that I call before the function to fill the drop down and in various other combinations.

Nothing has work so far.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You need call enhancement once you add options dynamically. `$("#id").selectmenu("refresh");`.

Answer (score 0):

The jQM enhanced select menu widget writes the current value in a SPAN that is a sibling of the select element in the DOM.  You can clear it with:

```
mySelect.siblings('span').empty();
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/h58qg/1/)**

Comment: Selectmenu should be refreshed, that's all http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/h58qg/2/

Comment: @Diomedes, please create a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem. You can look at this and edit/update to create your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/h58qg/4/